# Is there a jquery clone of ext.js' toolbar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a jquery equivalent of ext.js' toolbar (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/menu/menus.html). To be more precisely, my requirements are the following:

- the toolbar should consist of iconic and textual buttons and dropdown widgets
- buttons should either trigger actions directly or open submenus
- buttons and submenus should have the ability to remember the last selected state
- buttonsets should group multiple buttons and only allow one of them to be active

In short words, I'm looking for a real toolbar in jquery and not for some modified site menu. I experimented with the button/buttonset/menu widget in jquery ui 1.9m2, but found its IE performance rather poor. It also felt awkward to combine these isolated widgets into a logically connected toolbar.

Does anyone know of a better jquery toolbar plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [markItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/)